# Wordpress plugin creation how to execute .sql in order to insert multiple rows at activation of plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mysql

I am creating a wordpress plugin which upon activation i create my database table. I have an .sql file which has ~2000 rows of data and i would like to execute it after the creation of my database table. Which do you think is the best way to insert those data upon the plugin activation?

I know it is going to execute on activation hook - but is it possible to execute an .sql file or do i have to find another way and somehow execute each row through $wpdb->insert()?

If you need any further infomation please ask and i will provide - i also searched but couldn't find the same case.

Comment: You can use [`$wpdb->query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/) to insert multiple rows at once